# Affine scheme over a field; Can we give generic point coordinates?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-schemes

Let $X$ be an affine scheme over a field $k$. Let $K$ be the algebraic closure of $k$. We can consider the set of $k$-morphisms from $\mathrm{Spec\,} K$ to $X$. Is it possible to give generic points of $X$ coordinates in $K$?

Comment: As a follow up question, when we consider the set of k-morphisms from Spec K to X, is it true that the image of Spec K in the space of X can never be the generic point?

Comment: I think I was confused by the "coordinates"! Disregard my comment. For any point $x\in X$ you have a morphism $\operatorname{Spec} \kappa (x) \to X$.

Comment: A morphism $\text{Spec}(K)\to X$ is the data of a point $x\in X$ and an embedding $k(x)\hookrightarrow K$. So, you're really asking whether $K(X)$ (the function field of $X$) can be embedded in $\overline{k}$. The answer is *yes..sometimes*--if and only if $X$ is zero-dimensional iff $X$ is (physically) a finite set of points.